# How to fix text editor when using .cshtml in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have looked around and have not found any answers that have solved the issue. The problem is that when I try to edit in a .cshtml file none of the text is color coded like it should, everything is like it would be if it was in notepad. I have tried to reinstall and install again but this just gave me the same problem. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing MVC3? That's where the syntax highlighting I believe is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this extension:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8dc77b9c-7c83-4392-9c46-fd15f3927a2e/?SRC=Home

According to the "Gu" you should have everything you need if you installed MVC3. Maybe try uninstalling and re-installing.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/11/09/announcing-the-asp-net-mvc-3-release-candidate.aspx

Comment: That was it I was missing the razor plugin. Thank you for helping me fix my problem!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the cshtml files are slightly ahead of visual studio (2010)... There may be 2 options, see below...

"There are two options here: you can open your .cshtml files in Visual Studio using the HTML editor or open them using the WebMatrix beta which has built in support for Razor syntax highlighting." - http://mvcdev.com/mvc-3-preview-1-razor-syntax-highlighting-when-using-visual-studio-2010/